# Sprite Kit Shader Uniforms Ignored

Tags: opengl-es, sprite-kit, glsl

The shader that I'm using relies upon the position of the tiles in my game. I haven't found anything on using attribute variables with SKShader objects, so I went with updating the uniform variables. But it would seem that the shader won't communicate with the variables, especially once their values have been updated and changed. I am trying to make a basic lighting effect, but I can't get anything out of the shader at all. Any help? My code for the shader and for the Objective C classes are below.

## Shader

```
uniform float midX, midY;
uniform float posX;
uniform float posY;

void main()
{
    vec4 temp = SKDefaultShading(); // get the default shading
    float lightRad = 200.0; // Light radius
    float dist = distance(vec2(posX, posY), vec2(midX, midY)); // location of the light on the screen
    vec4 color = vec4(1.0, 0, 0.0, (float)(dist / lightRad)); // creates an alpha gradient for the light. (falloff)

    if (dist < lightRad) // only applies the light color if the distance from the light to the tile is smaller than the radius of the light
    {
        gl_FragColor = temp * color; // applies the color
    }
    else // otherwise, do nothing
    {
        gl_FragColor = temp; 
    }
}
```

## Code

```
- (void) loadShaders
{
    SKUniform* posX = [SKUniform uniformWithName:@"posX" float: 0.0f]; // adds the x position (with a placeholder value)
    SKUniform* posY = [SKUniform uniformWithName:@"posY" float: 0.0f]; // adds the y position (with a placeholder value)

    [_shader addUniform:posX];
    [_shader addUniform:posY];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _array.count; i++) // Loop through all tiles
    {
        float x = ((i % 100) - 13.5f) * 15.0f; // Calculate x pos of the tile
        float y = ((1 - (i / 100)) + 6.5f) * 15.0f; // Calculate y pos of the tile
        SKUniform* uniX = [[_tMap getShader] uniformNamed:@"posX"]; // get the uniform with the name posX
        uniX.floatValue = x; // set the value of that uniform

        SKUniform* uniY = [[_tMap getShader] uniformNamed:@"posY"]; // get the uniform with the name posY
        uniY.floatValue = y; // set the value of that uniform
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to sprite kit, and I'm also new to GLSL.

Comment: I think you are going to have some real problems with this approach. Changing a uniform will result in the shader getting recompiled and performance goes right out the window. I would suggest that you try to rethink you approach so that a specific shader can be shared across multiple tiles and you instead update the (X,Y) coordinates of the tile to get some change in the presentation on a per tile basis.

Comment: Well the same shader is being used across all the map tiles. All I need to do is calculate the distance from the tile to the point I specify on the screen. That's really all I'm trying to do. Is there a better way to accomplish this task? thanks for responding.

Comment: Your approach just does not make sense. There is only 1 variable for a uniform defined for an execution run of the shader. But, your code loops over and sets a uniform value multiple times. If you are going to read N values then it would make more sense to read values from a texture that you treat like a 2D array. Try to simplify your approach until you can get some shader output that makes some kind sense.